# Newbie question : N-N join that matches ALL a list

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Tables :

```
-- products --
   id

-- categories --
   id

-- products_categories --
   id
   product_id
   category_id
```

What could be a SQL query that returns all the products IDs that matches ALL a given list of category_ids ?

Example : Given the list (3, 4, 5) I would like all product_ids that have AT LEAST (could be more) the category id 3 and the category id 4 and the category id 5 ?

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). It sounds like you want [division with a remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) and an empty divisior is probably not an issue in your case.

Comment: BTW SQL works best with rows of data in tables, so you query will be easier to write and generalize if your 'list' `(3, 4, 5)` is modelled as three rows in a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.id
    FROM PRODUCTS p
    JOIN PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES pc ON pc.product_id = p.id
    JOIN CATEGORIES c ON c.id = pc.category_id
   WHERE c.id IN (3,4,5)
GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 3
```

This is popularly known as [Celko's division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

The `COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)` must equal the number of values specified in the `IN` clause.  Otherwise, duplicates of 4/3/5/etc would be false positives. However, if all the pairs of `product_id, category_id` are guaranteed to be unique, `DISTINCT` can be omitted.

Comment: You can skip the joins to `PRODUCTS` and `CATEGORIES` since he's only interested in the ID's

Comment: @Magnus: I agree for this example, but IMO it's simplified so I chose the most likely real-world approach

Answer (score 0):

Another option that can be read as a double negative:

Show all products for which there is no category in (3,4,5) for which there is no match with that product.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM CATEGORIES c 
        WHERE c.id IN (3,4,5)
          AND NOT EXISTS
              ( SELECT *
                FROM PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES pc
                WHERE pc.product_id = p.id
                  AND pc.category_id = c.id
              )
      )
```

This is popularly known as [Date's division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).